# pandas timeseries and R zoo

Tags: r, pandas, zoo

I get really stuck with this silly task :

I have two Pandas time series. Some time indexes may be different between them. I want, for the both series to get rid of the lines containing different time stamps, and keep, for both, only the lines with common time stamps.

I have the same issue with two zoo series in R.

To give an example, here are my series :

```
a = 2015-05-01 15.2
    2015-05-02 16.3
    2015-05-03 17.4
    2015-05-04 18.5
    2015-05-05 19.6

b = 2015-05-04 'a'
    2015-05-05 'b'
    2015-05-06 'c'
```

And then result I want to reach is :

```
a = 2015-05-04 18.5
    2015-05-05 19.6        

b = 2015-05-04 'a'
    2015-05-05 'b'
```

So that I keep only rows for which the time index is in the intersection of the time indices of the old series. How can that be Done with Pandas.Series? and with R zoo?

Please excuse me if the question appears to be silly. I really searched a lot without success. By the way, what is this operation called? Merging? Aligning?

Thanks a lot for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In R with zoo it would be: `merge(a, b, all = FALSE, retclass = NULL)`.  Note that (1) `all=FALSE` returns the intersection only and (2) `retclass=NULL` returns the merged series by writing the outputs back to the arguments.

Below is a self contained reproducible example.

```
# define inputs and read them into R as zoo objects

Lines.a = "2015-05-01 15.2
    2015-05-02 16.3
    2015-05-03 17.4
    2015-05-04 18.5
    2015-05-05 19.6"

Lines.b <- "2015-05-04 a
    2015-05-05 b
    2015-05-06 c"

library(zoo)
a <- read.zoo(text = Lines.a)
b <- read.zoo(text = Lines.b)

# merge the inputs and show result

merge(a, b, all = FALSE, retclass = NULL)

a
## 2015-05-04 2015-05-05 
      18.5       19.6 
b
## 2015-05-04 2015-05-05 
     a          b
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works. I also noticed that it does not work if I get rid of retclass = NULL in the parameters. Can you explain it a little? I do not find it in the help. On another hand, all = FALSE seems to be the default, do you confirm?

Comment: The `merge.zoo` default is `all = TRUE` and `retclass = NULL` *is* documented. Look at the help file for `merge.zoo`, not the one for `merge`.

Answer (score 3):

In pandas, there is an `align` operation, and would work like this:

```
a, b = a.align(b, join='inner')
```

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly. Can you advise for a tutorial for the other join possibilities (outer ..)?

Comment: Please, let me abuse your kindness. What if I had 3 or more time series a, b and c?
Doing

    a, b = a.align(b, join='inner')
    a, c = a.align(c, join='inner')

does not guarantee that the resulting 3 time series have the same time indices. Do I have to do all the possible alignments? In R, the function merge seems to accept any number of series.

Comment: @volatile you could nest or chain. I prefer chaining the `join` method: `a.join(b, [options]).join(c, [different options]).join(...)`

Comment: You could also use `concat`, like  `df = pd.concat([a,b,c], join='inner', axis=1)`, and then split the DataFrame back into Series